# Is an answer I wrote really that unclear?

Tags: discussion

I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379979/transactiontoolargeexception-when-trying-to-send-binary-content-using-intents/39381772#39381772) to a fairly complex Android development question. It identifies the exact line in the Android library where the questioner's exception is thrown. I don't know how the answer could be more precise than it already is.

Still the questioner has referred to it as "not an answer" and tried to start an argument with me apparently because I didn't provide a step-by-step procedure for fixing his code.

The questioner's latest comment is

> I guess the part I'm trying to understand is why this causes a crash now

which is exactly what my answer explains.

So,

#### Question 1: is the answer as written really so hard to understand?

I am interested in answers to this question from people who have some knowledge of Android development, but also from others.

#### Question 2: what can you possibly do when faced with this kind of attitude?

Let me add: the answer is not vague. It has a very useful clue for a developer on the other side of the conversation who is willing to do his part.

I would normally use a comment for something like this to avoid arguments about the quality of an answer, but sometimes comments don't offer enough room for necessary details.

Comment: stepping away from said question would be a good start.

Comment: PEBCAC's are a common phenomenon. Just move on.

Comment: You've indicated yourself that the question doesn't contain enough information to actually provide a solution.  The correct thing to do when in that situation is to *not answer the question* and instead vote to close it and help the author clarify it until it has enough information to be answerable.  Posting guesses or very broad/vague answers that you can't know are correct results in these kinds of problems.  In this specific case the OP *is* right in that your answer *isn't* an answer.

Comment: It's definitely not the case that this answer is nothing but a vague guess. I have updated the question to explain that.

Comment: @x-code You open with stating where you think the problem is "most likely" to be (a term you also use in the 3rd paragraph to describe where to find the problem).  You use the term "wild guess" before mentioning another option.  And of course your last comment says, "Only you know your code." as your way of saying that you can't say what's actually wrong.  So yes, your answer *is* guessing.  You even say as much.  You have said yourself that you don't have enough information to provide an answer.  Given that, you shouldn't have posted an answer anyway.

Comment: @Servy: the answer was edited over time; maybe that was a mistake. The precise answer begins with the line "the exception from your stack trace..." Parts of the answer that are less precise I added because he did not seem to "get it."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What does PEBCAC stand for?

Comment: @dorukayhan http://de.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=1189933&term=Pebcac Aka PEBKAC where K means keyboard.

Comment: I can see both sides. While point out the source of the problem is helpful in its own right and might be enough for many people to actually fix it, the OP is correct in that it's not truly an answer. An answer solves the problem; it doesn't highlight it. Now, I know you said you only posted it as an answer because the comments are too restrictive. However, for that, the best thing to do is post a community wiki. It's basically an "answer", but one you don't get rep for, and one that doesn't have to actually be a true-blue answer.

Comment: The OP asked why the exception was being thrown. The answer highlights where it's thrown in the source, which states "too much data". If the OP can't figure out how to send less data, that doesn't invalidate the answer's explanation.

Comment: I read undeleted comments that are posted in posts below and I don't find them too aggressive or offensive. They were just like a reply to your comments, and as far as answer goes you have written yourself that it is not a complete answer, so OP would be requiring clarification for his doubts from your end.

Answer (score 29):

If you've stated what you believe to be a clear and correct answer to the question, you feel that you've sufficiently responded to their comments, and they still want more, you're under no obligation to provide it. At that point, if you feel there's nothing to improve in your answer, I'd just walk away. You've done your best.

I wouldn't get into or prolong an argument with someone about this. I should note that the comments there were civil and polite up until you left the comment

> Just read the answer. It's pointless to go back and forth in the comments.

which comes off as a little hostile. It was at that point that the asker became more defensive, and I decided to clean up the remaining comments.

I don't think the comments were heading for an argument before that point, so had you walked away before then I don't think this would have been a problem. Again, if you feel your answer is explained as well as you can, and there's nothing more to add, there's not much more to do.

Comment: Well thanks for cleaning up the comments. The last comment of mine that remains, "looking at the way you use built-in classes that might have a lot of instance state is the only new suggestion I have. Only you know your code" represents me trying to do exactly what you recommend: walk away. That was followed by another comment from the user trying to goad or insult me into giving the answer he wanted. You haven't quoted that.

Comment: The comment of mine that you describe as "a little hostile" was actually a little annoyed, for a good reason: the OP was not allowing me to walk away.

Comment: @x-code _"the OP was not allowing me to walk away."_ Only _you_ can make you go back to that question and post a new comment. If someone answers after your attempt to walk away, you don't have to reply to them. The other user can't force you to come back and type in the comment box. (I'm not trying to say you did wrong, just pointing out that you could have still walked away, you just chose to keep coming back.)

Comment: @Kendra Advice like that is easier to give than it is to take. My comments (which are mostly gone now) although I admit they showed some annoyance, were all attempts to end a conversation that was turning into an argument. The OPs comments were insults, and "the Internet" seems to think that failing to respond to an insult is admitting the insult is true.

Comment: @x-code Don't worry about what "the Internet" thinks. And true, advice like that is certainly easy to give and harder to follow, but I've managed it a number of occasions right here on Meta (with a few failings to follow it, I will readily admit) so it's possible. It takes discipline and intent to follow, but I believe you can manage it if you put forth the effort. It won't be easy and you won't do it every time, but try to remember that it's not someone else's fault if you don't walk away.

Comment: For posterity, [here's how the commenting went](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo2rt.png). These aren't really insults, and each of the asker's comments were only in response to ones you left. Again, without that first comment I think the tone of this exchange would have been much different.

Comment: @Brad Larson I think you should undelete those comments because my last comment was an attempt to de-escalate an argument and walk away, and it worked in the sense that the OP stopped insulting and/or pestering me.

Comment: @x-code A suggested read: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks. The concept of help vampirism isn't completely  new to me, but that is a good article about it. The reason I would post here in meta even though I already kinda knew the type of answers that I was likely to get, is that I have a strong sense that the official policies at Stack Overflow encourage help vampirism. The tendency in this answer to interpret the OP's comments generously, and mine ungenerously, is an example of that policy, or maybe just attitude. It is not healthy for the programming community.

Comment: @x-code I generally agree with your reasonings. Though you just move on IMO.

Comment: @x-code: the site's official policies strongly discourage engaging in discussion, which is critical to not *enabling* vampirism (see πάντα's link): if you keep responding to someone who asks for a little more help, and a little more help... They'll keep asking. Folks should be encouraged to walk away from any situation where their effort won't be rewarding to them. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: FYI, I've deleted a sub-thread in the comments here. I think x-code asked a sincere question and deserved a sincere answer, which he got; please don't abuse the author of the question or the answer here by using this as a soapbox to air irrelevant grievances. If you want to vent, join me in [the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: @Shog9 I've seen it instantiated in the "please consider moving to chat" warning (and maybe that warning includes a policy link, I can't remember), but do you have a link for `"the site's official policies strongly discourage engaging in discussion"`? (And, that chameleon question link was a good read)

Comment: [This is a reasonably succinct document on the purposes for which comments are preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)... and discouraged... @henry. Beyond that, the system itself tries to discourage you via the chat prompt, and if ignored moderators will get a flag and probably just delete a bunch of comments.

Comment: @Shog9 ok not sure why the chastising ellipses. Anyway. I think it's a good policy, just wondered where I could read it.

Comment: I love ellipses, @henry. A message without ellipses is a message without soul.

Comment: In the past I've posted answers that I've felt were better than the questioner thought. I have satisfaction from all the up votes my answers have received.